# DWR 3.0.2 in Spring and Spring MVC version 3.0 integration issue(name space error for schemalocation) Maven project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dwr

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22ePM.png) I have an old Spring webmvc application and DWR integration is required. But when i try to integrate the same, namespace error keeps coming.

servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beansxmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">

    
    
    <!-- jsp loaded --><bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>




<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property value="true" name="alwaysUseFullPath"></property> 
  <property name="mappings">
    <props> 
      <prop key="/dwr/*">dwrController</prop>
      <prop key="/">HController</prop>
    </props>
 </property> 
</bean>

    <bean id="dwrController" class="com.Controller.java.DwrController" />
    <bean id="HController" class="com.HelloController.java.HelloController" />
    <dwr:remote name="myRemoteMethod" service="MyRemoteObject">
</dwr:remote> 
<!-- <dwr:controller id="dwrController" debug="true" />  error caused  -->

<!-- <bean class="com.Controller.java..DWRService" id="dwrService"> 
  <dwr:remote javascript="dwrService"> 
    <dwr:include method="getEnquiries"/> 
  </dwr:remote> 
</bean> -->

</beans>
```

when i add dwr 3.0xsd line in schemaLocation of namespace error coming for dwr like  referenced file contains errors (http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd=org/directwebremoting/spring/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd). For more information, right click on the . any alternative opensource available for DWR for spring version 3.0 I am using spring project only, no spring boot

Comment: Remove the `=org/directwebremoting/spring/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd` part from the namespace URL. That is wrong.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried that I tried using  "http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd", also but didn't work same error was coming

Comment: Where did I state you needed to remove the 3.0 version, I only stated you need to remove the part after. Also what error do you keep mentioning? The XSD should come from the jar you have included for DWR.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried with the way u have mentioned using url http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd . the error is still coming (image attached at top)

Comment: Have you actually tried running the application... Feels like you get sidetracked by an error in your IDE which tries to retrieve the file from the web, where it doesn't exist anymore.